# Distance from image of bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A:H\rightarrow H$ be a bounded linear operator on Hilbert space $H$. Suppose we have $x\in H$ and $r>\mathrm{dist}(x,A(H))=\inf\{\|x-Ah\|,\ h\in H\}$. How to prove that then there exist exactly one $y_0\in H$ such that $\|x-Ay_0\|\le r$ and $\|y_0\|=\inf\{\|y\|,\ y\in H, \|x-Ay\|\le r\}$? Is it possible to replace $\inf$ by $\min$ ?

Comment: if the image of $H$ by $A$ is bounded, then $A y = 0$, and what you said is false.

Comment: Why ? There are a lot of nonzero bounded operators. The algebra $B(H)$ is nonzero.

Comment: @user1952009 The image is always a linear subspace, so it can not be bounded, unless it is $\{0\}$ which corresponds to the trivial zero operator.

Comment: @user1952009 my bad !

Comment: Bounded operators means that the norm is bounded, i.e. $A$ is continuous.

Comment: ? For example let $A:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a projection onto $\mathbb{R}$. Then $A$ is bounded ($\|A\|\le 1$) but $A\neq 0$.

Comment: But where we need boundedness of image ? Bounded operator means, by definition, that its norm is bounded.

Comment: @mikis :  I finally understood. for you, $dist(x_0,A(H))$ means that the minimal distance between $x_0$ and $y \in A(H)$. for us, it means that every $y \in A(H)$ is at a distance $<r$ to $x$. so write it rigorously, and you'll easily get what you desired.

Comment: Ok, I edited main post.